# Windows Server 2008 - Run scheduled task whether user is logged or not, using a network mapped drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

On Windows Server 2003, I used to create some scheduled task which can be run whether the user is logged or not. The scheduled task runs a batch script which copy some files on a mapped network drive (e.g there is a letter to the mapped drive). 
Since Windows Server 2008, I can't do that anymore because the task scheduler has been 'improved'. If I check the radio button 'run if user is logged in', the scheduled task works fine, but if I choose 'run whether user is logged or not', It does not work. I explain : the jobs runs and the batch script starts, but the copy does not work because of an "access denied" to the mapped drive.

Precisions :

1) I have to use the mapped network drive, I can't use UNC path (like \\server)

2) The scheduled task has to be able to run if the user is disconnected.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when your task runs, the drive map doesn't exist in the context of the user/session the task is being run as. I can think of three ways to solve the problem:

- modify your batch file to map the drive before accessing it
- use the "Configure for" combo box to select "Windows Server 2003, ..." in the task settings
- reference the network location by UNC (not alawys possible)

Comment: Thank you for you quick response.

1) My batch doesn't map the drive because the drive is already mapped. We used a soft called WebDrive which maps the network drive

2) There is the option "Configure for" but there is not 'Windows Server 2003' in the list. I only have Vista, Seven, 2008 and 2008 R2

3) This is a bit complicated, but this is absolutely impossible to  reference the network location by UNC ... :( I have to use the mapped drive letter...

Comment: Besides, I agree with you on the fact that the drive map may not exist at the moment the task runs. Am I trying to do something impossible ? This is infortunate because it works perfectly on Windows Server 2003 and many servers are already configured ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebDrive. However, the dire can't be allready mapped because otherwise you would be able to access it. You could try to use the usual way to map the drive via `net use` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx). If this is also impossible you could try to create the mapping vie WebDrive and remove it after the task is done.